# Can a Dementor destroy a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, dementors

If a Dementor can consume and destroy a person's soul, and a Horcrux is part of someone's soul in an object, could harry have just found a Horcrux and thrown it at a Dementor, so that it could destroy it for him?

Comment: No direct evidence of it in canon, but presumably, Dementors evolved to such the soul out of a **Human**. E.g. it would be the same degree of difficulty as if you gave a screwed-tightly thermos full of milk to a cat :)